# Can we update some object without stopping the program?

Tags: c++, linux, object

There is a program written in C++ and running in linux box. It has a configuration file given to it at starting point. I came to know that it can sometime support updating the configuration file without the need to stop the program.

As the configuration update means eventually updating some of the objects(member variables) inside the running program. I want to understand the idea behind it. How we can update the object inside a running program?

I am a beginner and want to understand the concept behind it? Or is it something trivial that only I am missing the point?

Comment: You could put it in a shared library that you load at runtime (`dlopen` + `dlsym`). When you want to replace it,  overwrite the old shared library, signal the process to reload it and act upon that (`dlclose` and then `dlopen` + `dlsym` again) - if you break the ABI that the program uses, you'll need to recompile and restart the process though

Comment: @TedLyngmo Great, I'll read more about this approach. Is this just one of the way to avoid bouncing the program or is it something very standard procedure in the cpp world?

Comment: I have no clue actually. I've never done it myself but I've used `dlopen` etc to load libraries at runtime many times so this was the first thing that popped into my head :-) I think it'll be tricky to get it right though. All objects from the shared library that are alive need to save their state and then deleted, after the library has been reloaded,  new objects will have to be created to restore the state (best they can).

Comment: `dlopen+dlsym` is for loading changes to C++ code, not to reload a configuration file. Programs don't use any magic to update object fields based on new configuration, it's the same `myobject.mymember = "myvalue";` as always. You just have to write the program in such a way that you can respond to an event (traditionally SIGHUP), trigger the code that reads the configuration, and make sure that the program logic includes it

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, I was reading it wrong. I was thinking object _file_ ... :-) Jeez.  Aadil: Just disregard my comments about shared library stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope the configuration so that it is reread when necessary.

Here's a very simple example

```
void do_work()
{
    Configuration config(path_to_config_file);
    while (not_changed(path_to_config_file))
    {
        // do one unit of work
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        do_work();
    }
}
```

Program starts, enters the loop and calls `do_work`. `do_work` constructs a `Configuration` object that reads the configuration file and stores the settings. Then it enters a loop that checks for a change to the configuration file and does work if the file has not changed.

If the file has changed, the loop exits, `do_work` exits, the `Configuration` object is destroyed and the loop in `main` calls `do_work` to load the new configuration and get back to work.

Precisely how you would implement `not_changed` depends on the system. It could be as simple as looking for a change in the modification timestamp on the configuration file.

In a real program you'll want to add some extra smarts to allow the user to exit the program.